# C++ Optimal way of returning multidimensional array from function, pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I need to return an array of class objects from a function. I understand from research that the best way to do this is with a pointer, but is this the best way given my program design, and the need to access this from multiple CPP files?

main.cpp

```
#include <class.h>
#include <functions.h>

int main(){
Class Object[2][]; //define second dimension here?
some_function(); //should return / create the array with filled in elements.
int var = arr[2][3]; // want to be able to do something like this in main
}
```

functions.cpp

```
void some_function(){
// assign values
arr[2][3] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Try a vector. `vector<vector<int>> some_function() {...}` Of course you'll need C++11 to use `<int>>` and not `<int> >`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really use `std::vector<std::vector<Object> >` for your multi-dimensional array.  Using raw arrays is error prone, and since you're using C++ anyways, why not make use of something as useful as the `std::vector` which automatically resizes when needed.

You can even return the `vector` from your function like so:

`std::vector<std::vector<Object> > my_function() { /* do something */  return some_vector; }`

Comment: And if you are using C++11 and Object is moveable this is also optimal (in that you don't copy everything in the vectors).  If you aren't using C++11 maybe put your objects into boost or tr1 shared_ptr.

Comment: Does returning a vector like this, with no pointer, enable the vector array to be returned without any bulk data copying?

Comment: @MartinJames given a decent compiler, yes.

Comment: @Martin: yes, look up Return Value Optimization.